# Gradle Artifactory Plugin - Difference Between Plugin And Repositories Block

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

I am using Gradle 7.3.3 with the Artifactory Plugin.
I have notices that there is a section to resolve dependencies in the `artifactory` plugin section itself:

```
artifactory {
  contextUrl = "https://my.repo"
  publish {...}

  resolve {
    repository {
      repoKey = '<my repo key>'
      maven = true
    }
  }
}
```

However, there is also the `repository` block which contains a reference to a repository:

```
repositories {
  maven {
    url "https://my.repo/<my repo key>"
  }
  mavenLocal()
}
```

My question is what is the difference between these two?
do I need to use only one of them? Do I need to put same values in both?
I didn't see any documentation in JFrog docs.

Answer (score 1):

A rule of thumb says that undocumented methods are internal and should not be used. AFAIK, the two methods should be **identical**.

Unless you have a very specific use case with a rare repository configuration, you'd may prefer using only the official Gradle's [repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) scope. Just make sure to use the Artifactory repository above `mavenCentral()` in order to enjoy the benefits of Artifactory - build info, performance, security, etc.

Sources:

1. [Official documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin)
2. [Examples](https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples)

Comment: Just to add more background information: the `repository` block below `artifactory` used to exist some time ago officially. It must have been removed in favour of Gradle's `repositories` approximately in spring 2018, see https://github.com/jfrog/project-examples/commit/e7146659bd3a56b1e405cdaa18c5c9a9cf39edf3 as an indication.

Comment: The complete removal happened precisely in the Gradle Artifactory plugin 5.0.0. You can find more details at this link: https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-gradle-plugin/#-overview under "Migrating from Version 4 to Version 5 of the Plugin".